# How should I go about making a simple mobile app? Titanium or native?

Tags: android, ios, mobile, titanium, titanium-mobile

I have a very simple app idea that I want to make on my free time. My skills are all LAMP stack web development, so I figured I would use Appcelerator's Titanium to make the app for both mobile operating systems.

However, after starting Titanium, I've run into a lot of weird errors. For example, the Android simulator does not work correctly and cannot pick up the user's location. I also cannot get ajax requests to work.

Titanium seems buggier than just developing in objective-c or Java. I'm wondering if it's worth it for me to struggle with Titanium or just learn how to develop for each operating system individually. Any ideas?

Comment: This isn't the sort of question that can really be "answered," but I'll say that I had similar to concerns to you when I looked into Titanium and other similar products. I ended up going with standard native development, but there's some non-trivial up-front effort involved in learning native development skills that may not make sense for all apps.

Comment: @cloudymusic I was just asking people's opinions because I don't know how reliable Titanium is vs how hard iOS is to learn.

Comment: Well wish me luck XD I'm busting out the first iOS tutorial now haha

Comment: From my experience I suggest you for Titanium since you're a web developer. Titanium need only Javascript and it's API's. I'm working with Titanium for last few months. I felt it's nice. And it is much easier to study and understand Titanium than studying objective-C or Java. Also please refer http://www.sapandiwakar.in/technical/api-research-study-iphone-and-android-applications/. There are a lot of advantages for using cross platform tools :)

Answer (score 2):

If your app idea is truly "very simple" then I would highly recommend learning the basics of each development platform and starting to make it for each. Even in doing that you would better understand what's going on underneath Titanium. The errors and issues would make more sense and you might perhaps know where to look for help.

That's just my opinion. I am, at this very moment, doing some iOS tutorials just so I can at least be familiar with how iOS apps work. :)

Comment: Also, I say this because where I work we had a project that originally started with Titanium. Since then, the people we worked for quickly wanted us to start developing the app using both iOS and Android natively.

Comment: My app is basically going to show a map with your current location with two buttons.  The buttons send POST and GET requests and bring you to a new map mage.  That is it!  So you think it's simple enough that I should start in iOS then go to Android?

Comment: I don't see why not. I just can't personally speak for iOS since I have not developed in it. But I would imagine it would be just as simple to create that in iOS as it would be in Android. I also just like learning new things XD so that's why it is simply my own opinion.

Answer (score 1):

There's pros and cons to each approach. I usually explain it to clients like this:

You can choose to develop using a third party, cross-platform SDK (such as Titanium, Unity, Phone Gap, etc), and it may reduce development time. However, there is a cost to such- the app will be a bigger download because it includes both the code written for your app and the code for the cross-platform tool. Further, the code may be slower (not as performant) than natively written code (depending on how the cross platform kit works, it could potentially be as performant perhaps, but it could never be faster than native code).

From Titanium's website (see http://developer.appcelerator.com/question/91121/reducing-the-size-of-titanium-based-application):

Question : `How can we reduce the size of a Titanium based Application? My Application whose Resources Files are just about 800 Kb, generates around 5.7 MB sized App in Debug mode and 5.2 MB in Release mode?`

Answer : `The Titanium build scripts try and analyze your source code and optimize the generated binary to only include the Titanium modules that are necessary. However, it does remain the case that our binaries are much larger than native binaries, since we need to ship our platform code and a JavaScript interpreter with the application.`

Ultimately, the question comes down to this- which is more important for your project: (1) ease and speed of development or (2) performance and size of the application?

If you're building a cross-platform game, developing such natively may not mean a few days of additional development time, but perhaps a few months or years. Further, some of these tools (such as Unity in particular) may already have pre-packaged solutions to problems you'll have if writing it natively (such physics engines that will save you a lot of time). In this case, you're probably better off creating your app using a cross-platform SKD.

(You also have the benefit that users are more likely to be understanding that the app is so big, because it is after all, a game and users are familiar with long downloads for such.)

However, if you're creating a fairly simplistic app, or an app for business, media, etc where the size of the download is important (perhaps users might not be willing to wait a long time to download and use your app) and/or performance matters most, go with writing it natively.

In your case, as you mention that you're trying to make "a very simple app," it may be best to write it natively. Ultimately, this is a choice you have to make weighing the pros and cons of both options.

Comment: Thanks for your great insight.  Basically I'm making a geolocation app with two buttons that send ajax calls and show a new map after interacting with a back end.  It does very few things but those things could be hard to implement, I just don't know. Titanium seemed really buggy and from your description I think I want it to be native anyway.  Ultimately I want a small file size and a great user experience.

Comment: Yeah, on iOS, this app is pretty easy. It would probably take an experienced programmer only a few hours. I imagine that it would be similar for Android side. Even starting from scratch, I imagine that you can learn how to do this in a weak or so. Checkout Ray Wenderlich's site (see http://www.raywenderlich.com/) . He's got a few tutorials that should help with what you're doing specifically (in particular, http://www.raywenderlich.com/21365/introduction-to-mapkit-in-ios-6-tutorial and http://www.raywenderlich.com/2965/how-to-write-an-ios-app-that-uses-a-web-service). Good luck!

Comment: Actually, I'd recommend using `AFNetworking` instead of `ASIHTTPRequest` (because `ASIHTTPRequest` is older and not supported any longer, yet it's still recommended in Ray's tutorial). Here's a good tutorial on starting `AFNetworking`, too: http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/ios-sdk_afnetworking/

Comment: there are quite a few invalid comments here about performance and appcelerator in general, but the question was closed for the proper reason which is that this is really just asking for someones opinion

Comment: @AaronSaunders, perhaps this might be moot at this point (as the question has been closed- although, I do agree it was closed for the right reason) but could you share your opinion about said "invalid comments"? If I've been in error, I'd be happy to change my views given sufficient evidence of such. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If the application is simple, go native.
1 month ago my skills were also LAMP, but as developing for android has much documentation and many tutorials, I could easily get the hang of it. Anyone with programming notion achieve the same.

But it was as I said, much will depend on your situation. Like for example my application is based on a "webview" then why would not I go after non-native platforms.